# Maven -- how to find out all library dependency on parent pom

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am integrating a chaotic project, and some libraries has parent pom as SNAPSHOT, like this

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<version>2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Of course, I need to fix it.

However it's really hard for me to find out which library brings in that pom, since `mvn dependency:tree` does not show the parent poms.

For example if A depends on yyy and yyy has a parent pom of zzz, `mvn dependency:tree` won't display zzz. So it's hard for me to find out which library depends on a snapshot parent pom.

Is there a maven command that can display all the parent poms of all libraries I bring in?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this because parent pom's are handled differently than maven dependencies. So dependency:tree won't work. What you can try doing though is pull each dependency and their pom, parse through and check the parent. You may also try pulling up the effective pom and use it to parse through.